# Cypres function TYPE closes the previous entry

Tags: cypress

I've ran into a problem with cypress tests, that when I try to use type functionality on cypress it presses the input field where the remove button is located. My question is is it possible to move the click on the type function to other location? I'm adding a screenshot of behaviour and actual code.
[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADDrm.png)

[Here the "type" function clicks on remove element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1cmV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue, by finding the input first, then focusing on it and then the type funcion doesnt make the click itself.